# Why displaying my DateTime in a Textbox result to something different than displaying it directly into html?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my view I have the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.TextBox("Date2", Model.Date2)
  <br/>
  @Model.Date2
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

In my controller I have :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Home home){
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC! (after a submit)";
        home.Date2 = home.Date2.AddDays(1);
        return View("Index", home);
    }
```

The model is:

```
public class Home {
    public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
}
```

My question is : Why when I hit the submit button than the TextBox display not the date with 1 more day and the html that I output directly the date is?

### Edit:

If I step into MVC3 source code I can see that `private static MvcHtmlString InputHelper(...)` get the value parameter with the good date but later the code get the old value from `attemptedValue`... You can see the debug here https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2mTI.png

Comment: I do not really understand the question. Please rephrase.

Comment: I edited the question. In short : input doesn't give me the model value, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelState` saves a copy of the value input into the form field. Usually, if you're displaying a form in a `POST` action it's because validation has failed, so you want to re-display the "attempted" value input rather than a new one (this is what the input HTML helpers do by default).

To prevent it using the attempted value you could remove it from ModelState, e.g:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Home home)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC! (after a submit)";
        ModelState.Remove("Date2");
        home.Date2 = home.Date2.AddDays(1);
        return View("Index", home);
    }
```

Comment: In my case, I was loading data into a completely different view than the one I was coming from ... even in that case, it uses the "attempted" value?  I don't know what's more of a hack - changing the property name, or removing ModelState (in my case).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue ... it has to do with a property being passed to the Action having the same name as the property being returned from the Action, but having different values.

I can't answer why it is happening, but I can offer a solution on how to fix it (well, maybe not in your case since you are accepting and returning the same model).

```
public Action(IncomingViewModel incomingViewModel)
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    //incoming Date has different name than outgoing date
    viewModel.Date2 = incomingViewModel.OldDate2;
    return viewModel;
}
```

Like I said, this is kind of a hack in your case (in mine it wasn't that big of a stretch).  And again, it doesn't solve your problem, but might get you closer to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when returning a view from a post action all MVC helper methods (Html.Textbox, Html.DropdownList, etc) use the posted value to render the element instead of the actual object's value.

This makes returning a view with a validation error, for example, rendering exactly the user's input and not other value that could be changed in the action

Comment: Thank you, I give you +1 but will accept pjumble answer since it gaves me a workaround to fix the behavior.